# C++ unique_ptr and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use arrays with unique_ptr with no success.
What is the correct way to declare a unique_ptr of some size?
(size is some paramter).

```
unique_ptr<A[]> ptr = make_unique<A[]>(size);
```

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
    string str;
public:
    A(string _str): str(_str) {}
    string getStr() {
        return str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<A[]> ptr = make_unique<A[]>(3);
}
```

This is not working, however, if I delete the constructor of A, it works.
I want the 3 to represent the size of the array, and not an argument to A's constructor, how do I make that happen?

Comment: Hint: Use 4 spaces indentation to mark text as code

Comment: Why not using a `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<A>> ptr = make_unique<std::vector<A>>(3);`?

Comment: or alternatively `std::unique_ptr<std::array<A,3>> ptr = make_unique<std::array<A,3>>();`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that's an overkill! [Using a Grenade to kill an Ant] :-). either solutions requires the use of default constructors. He only needs to provide one and the code works

Comment: @WhiZTiM Yes, I've seen your answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think your comment is overkill. @user5618793 seems at a loss as to why he needs to default construct A. I too would be disappointed if it made no sense to default construct my class but I had to put it in a container. The only thing I would add is that the std::unique_ptr instantiated with an array or vector is only required if you need those structures on the heap. I find that it is often best to just do it on the stack. Use `std::array<A, 3>` or `std::vector<A>` straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is not working, however, if I delete the constructor of A, it
>   works.

When you removed the user defined constructor, the compiler implicitly generates a default one. When you provide a user defined constructor, the compiler doesn't implicitly generate a default constructor.

[`std::make_unique<T[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) requires the use of default constructors...

So, provide one, and all should work well

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A {
    string str;
public:
    A() = default;
    A(string _str): str(_str) {}
    string getStr() {
        return str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<A[]> ptr = make_unique<A[]>(3);
}
```

Comment: In this case, the 3 symbolizes the size of ptr ? I.e., ptr contains now 3 pointers?

Comment: @user5618793 This is the answer; in case you didn't realize it, there is an implicitly defined default constructor when no other constructors are present in your class, which is why your code works when you comment out the user-defined constructor.

Comment: @bku_drytt I know that, I just don't see use of 'A()' <- empty constructor in my code, so I don't understand the error

Comment: It symbolises the size of the contiguous memory holding the C-style array, that is 3 * sizeof(A). It does not hold 3 pointers pointing to A objects... this is why one needs a default constructor. If it held 3 pointers they could be nullptr and therefore you would not need a default parameterless constructor.

Comment: `make_unique<A[]>(3)` is making A[3] on the heap with each object, which must be a valid object, default constructed. You are calling A() because the objects must be valid (i.e. constructed). I really think that std::vector<A> should be used (i.e. a stack allocated object to manage growing arrays of A in the heap), that way you can specify the constructor when calling emplace or push_back. If you need a compile time bound use std::array.

Comment: @user5618793 The reason is that the overload of the `new` operator being used in the `std::make_unique` functions doesn't just allocate memory, it also tries to initialize the value.