# Create an array of smart pointers to a class with no default constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

I'm referring to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953688/c-unique-ptr-and-arrays) , Can we create an array of `std::unique_ptr` to a class which has deleted default constructor as below, How to pass the `string` argument.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>  
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A 
{
    string str;
public:
    A() = delete;
    A(string _str): str(_str) {}
    string getStr() 
    {
        return str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<A[]> ptr = make_unique<A[]>(3);
    unique_ptr<A[]> arr[3] = make_unique<A[]>(3);
    // Do something here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are asking about *array of `std::unique_ptr`*, but you have *`std::unique_ptr` to an array*.

Comment: Please clarify whether you mean "unique_ptr to an array" as in your code, or "array of smart pointers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with `make_unique`. But you can use this:

```
unique_ptr<A[]> ptr(new A[3]{{"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}});
```

Before C++11 - it was very hard (that can be done with placement new etc).

Comment: Could you be more specific about why we can't do that with `std::make_unique`, or some reference would be helpful.

Comment: @Panch just because `make_unique` for array has only one method (that one, that receives size).

Answer (score 7):

For an array of smart pointers:

```
unique_ptr<A> ptr[3];

for (auto& p : ptr)
    p = make_unique<A>("hello");
```